# Are there any tools / libraries around to let me script things on my computer, triggered from a MIDI input?

Tags: midi

I've got a little 16 key drum pad, and I'd love to be able to keep it next to my keyboard and set up some commands to be run when I hit each pad.

Firing off command-line stuff would be ideal to start with, but I've got no idea where to start?

Comment: There are a lot of options here. Which language(s) do you know / prefer? Which platform you are on (Windows, Mac, Linux)? I'm using pyPortMidi and pyGame to talk to a MIDI device, but that may not be best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need BOME's midi translator.

http://www.bome.com/products/miditranslator

You can convert midi into keypresses with it.